# inspect C++ template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates

Is there some utility which would allow me to inspect template instantiation?
my compiler is g++ or Intel.

Specific points I would like:

- Step by step instantiation.
- Instantiation backtrace (can hack this by crashing compiler.  Better method?)
- Inspection of template parameters.

@gf helpd me with simple type printing, [C++ template name pretty print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885597/c-template-name-pretty-print).

However I am getting into boost phoenix and template level makes it very hard to understand what is going on and I would like intelligent solution

also, if you have some techniques inspecting template instantiation, can you please share them.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With templates we simply don't have clean output facilities and there are no compilers i know of that allow you to directly view template instantiations. The closest i found regarding metaprogram debugging was [a paper on Templight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219007/c-template-metaprogramming-is-it-possible-to-output-the-generated-code).

For now the best utilities seem to be:

- [static asserts](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html) & [concept checks](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm) (clearly assert your assumptions)
- the mentioned instantiation backtraces (e.g. by using static asserts)
- letting instantiations generate warnings ([`boost::mpl::print`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/boost/mpl/print.hpp) might do it)
- a tracer, a custom class that gets passed as a template argument and is used to emit runtime output (introduced by [C++ Templates - The Complete Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201734842))

Comment: okay, I think you meant mpl::print.  I found it in the paper you linked

Comment: To add on the paper: There is an [implementation](http://plc.inf.elte.hu/templight/) available.