# Output the full type of a possibly failing typedef in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, typedef

I'm trying to output the full type of a typedef in the build log of Visual Studio; even for possibly failing typedefs, f.e. when a partial specialisation is missing.
My specific version is 2019 but i also tried and failed with 2010 and 2015.

The only possible solution for this i could find is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958202/output-the-type-of-a-typedef-at-compile-time-in-c-specifically-when-an-error) but it doesn't work in Visual Studio.

Here's the testcode:

```
template<typename T>
struct Printer;
template <typename T>
struct ST;
template <>
struct ST<int&> {
    typedef int T;
};
template <typename T>
struct S {
    Printer<typename ST<T>::T> t;
};
int main() {
    typedef int& intref;
    S<intref> testi;

    typedef float& floatref;
    S<floatref> testf;

    typedef short& shortref;
    Printer<shortref> testsi;
}
```

And [here is a godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/8YEj9z)

For this example, i'd like to see somewhere an output of

1. "**int**" for the existing specialization
2. "**float&**" for the missing specialization
3. "**short&**" or "**short int&**" for the simple case

Comment: It is *visual* C++, best to use the product the way it was intended.  Nobody ever looks at a build log, they hover the mouse over the red squiggles.  Which shows int&

Comment: @HansPassant That's the best interpretation of "visual" i've ever heard :) I updated the code to show the limits of the squiggles. I first hoped that the "Code Analysis" would correctly report the type and it does for the really trivial cases but for the one currently in the question it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

If I am placing the mouse cursor over the `test` incomplete object I can see the type passed as template argument see picture, it is not very clean but it is the only way I have found up to now.

[image]

Comment: I updated the code to show the limits of the squiggles. I first hoped that the "Code Analysis" would correctly report the type and it does for the really trivial cases but for the one currently in the question it doesn't.

Comment: @jesses what do you mean ? If my mouse hovers ```<floatref >``` in ```S<floatref> testf;``` I see the ```typedef float& floatref``` and for ```testf``` I have ```S<float &>```

Comment: Sorry, I oversimplified the example when i tried to narrow it down; in the codebase i have to work with the places where template expansion in the build log would be helpful are much more complex. I hope it's more clear now with the added missing specialization.

Comment: In addition to this method, it seems that there is no particularly good method to meet your needs.

Comment: @BarrnetChou there is the "Code Analysis" which sometimes outputs more than the compiler

Comment: So, do you mean that the complete type can be obtained by code analysis? Have you solved this problem? I searched a lot of information and did not find a better method.

Comment: @BarrnetChou In a few cases i observed "Code Analysis" to report more expanded types than the compiler. But for the code above it doesn't.

Comment: So, there is still no better solution to this problem.